# Comparing columns in two different files and producing three outputs

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have multiple paired files with headings xxx_1.txt and xxx_2.txt, yyy_1.txt and yyy_2.txt, etc. They are single column files with the following format:

xxx_1.txt:

```
#CHROM_POSREFALT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9107CA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9197CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9303TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_10635GA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_10836AG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11108AG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11121GA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11123CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11131CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11155AG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11166CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11186TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11233TG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11274GT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11472CG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11814GA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_11815CT
```

xxx_2.txt:

```
LocationMSHR1153_annotatedMSHR0491_Australasia
MSHR1153_annotated_1_56TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_226AG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_670AG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_817CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_1147TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_1660TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_2488AG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_2571GA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_2572TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_2698TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_2718TG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_3018TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_3424TC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_3912CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_4013GA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_4087GC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_4878CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_5896GA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_7833TG
MSHR1153_annotated_1_7941CT
MSHR1153_annotated_1_8033GA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_8888AC
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9107CA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9197CT
```

They are actually much longer than this. My goal is two compare each line and produce multiple outputs for the purpose of creating a venn diagram later on. So I need one file which lists all the lines in common which looks like this (in this case there is only one):

```
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9107CA
```

One file that lists everything specific to xxx_1 and one file which lists everything specific to xxx_2.

I have so far come up with this:

```
awk ' FNR==NR { position[$1]=$1; next} {if ( $1 in position ) {print $1 > "foundinboth"} else {print $1 > "uniquetofile1"}} ' FILE2 FILE1
```

The problem is I know how over 300 paired files to run through, and if I use this I have to change them manually each time. It also doesn't produce all the files at the same time. Is there a way to do this to loop through and change everything automatically? The files are paired so that the suffix at the end is different "`_1`" and "`_2`". I need it to loop through each paired file and produce everything I need at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
for f in *_1.txt; do                    # find files such as "xxx_1.txt"
    basename=${f%_*}                    # extract "xxx" portion
    if [[ -f ${basename}_2.txt ]]; then # make sure "xxx_2.txt" exists
        file1="${basename}_1.txt"       # assign bash variable file1
        file2="${basename}_2.txt"       # assign bash variable file2
        both="${basename}_foundinboth.txt"
        uniq1="${basename}_uniquetofile1.txt"
        uniq2="${basename}_uniquetofile2.txt"

        awk -v both="$both" -v uniq1="$uniq1" -v uniq2="$uniq2" '
                                        # pass the variables to AWK with -v option
            FNR==NR { b[$1]=$1; next }
            {
                if ($1 in b) {
                    print $1 > both
                    seen[$1]++          # mark if the line is found in file1
                } else {
                    print $1 > uniq1
                }
            }
            END {
                for (i in b) {
                    if (! seen[i]) {    # the line is not found in file1
                        print i > uniq2 # then it is unique to file2
                    }
                }
        }' "$file2" "$file1"
    fi
done
```

Please note that the lines in `*_uniquetofile2.txt` do not keep the original order.
If you need them to, please try to sort them for yourself or let me know.